# Using underscore (_) as a PHP function name

Tags: php

According to http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php, I should be able to use an underscore (_) as a function name:

> Function names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid
>   function name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any
>   number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression,
>   it would be expressed thus: [a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*.

However, the following kills my program without causing any errors:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo('start');
function _($x){return ($x)?htmlspecialchars($x):'nbsp;';}
echo('end');
```

I am using PHP Version 5.3.18. What don't I understand?

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: use double underscore instead __($x)

Comment: The above code worked for me. (PHP Version 5.3.10)

Comment: If you had error reporting turned on, you would have seen an error about redeclaring `_()`

Comment: @TimN.  Still no displayed error.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Comment: @user1032531 Try http://3v4l.org/l5d2i

Comment: Still not displaying errors, however, that question is outside of the scope of my original question.  Thank you all.

Comment: Adding php_value display_errors 1 to .htaccess allowed errors to be displayed.  Note that per the documentation, ini_set('display_errors',1); will not work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is already a built-in function called `_`; it is an alias for [`gettext`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php#refsect1-function.gettext-notes).

You are likely getting a `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare _()`, but the error may not be output to your screen depending on your setting for `display_errors`. You could also look at the `log_errors` directive.

Comment: Thanks. Never knew that.  Not documented very well: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php.  Why isn't it throwing some sort of error?

Comment: @user1032531 It does: `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare _()`

Comment: You must have error reporting turned off.  I get this output: `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare _() in foo.php on line 3`

Answer (score 4):

As cbuckley said, there is already a `gettext` alias defined with name `_`.  If you have gettext enabled `_` name is taken.

You better use double underscore (`__`). I use it frequently. Or you disable gettext.